# .htaccess Redirects wrong and looping

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to refer urls (e.g. from `page.php?page_id=1` to `page/1` or `page/pagename` or just `pagename`), using this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteBase /subdirectory/

# If user tries to access "subdirectory/page" without "get" then
RewriteRule ^page/ page.php [L]

# If user tries to access "subdirectory/page/1" or "subdirectory/pagename" then
RewriteRule ^page/1 page.php?page_id=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/pagename page.php?page_id=1 [L]

# If user tries to access "subdirectory/pagename" only then
RewriteRule ^pagename page.php?page_id=1 [L]
```

If I turn it off (`RewriteEngine Off` or even deleting the entire .htaccess file) and if I turn it on, it does the wrong thing - It redirect itself to parent directory (localhost `www` folder), e.g. from `subdirectory/page/etc.` to `page/etc.`. If it finally works, after I try again and again (and again and again...) to change it non-stop in order to make it work, It causes an infinite loop when it has a trailing slash (such as `page/1` or `page/somepage`) or it just not display the page properly (because the browser treats it like it was a real path / folder and not a slug)

I know I probably did something wrong (i'm new to .htaccess) but I don't know what... any thoughts?

Thank you very much.

**Update:** the .htaccess file is inside the "subdirectory" folder. There is another .htaccess file in the www folder (main folder of localhost that also include the "subfolder") which contains this:

```
# RewriteEngine On
# 
# ErrorDocument 404 /err.php?id=404
# ErrorDocument 403 /err.php?id=403
# ErrorDocument 500 /err.php?id=500
```

It's commented just because that this is the only way to disable it - I tried the "rewriteengine off", had no success

Comment: Do you need a RewriteBase, i.e. is the folder an alias to a physical directory? Where is the .htaccess placed? "If I turn it off... and if I turn it on, it does the wrong thing" - Is it even not looping when turned off?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Yes, because I need it to work within a specific folder. the folder is an alias to a physical directory. the .htaccess file placed inside the "subdirectory" folder

Comment: And you expect `/subdirectory/page.php` to be called when `/subdirectory/somePageOrDirectory...` is requested and doesn't exist?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I think there was a misunderstanding here.  I probably didn't explain it well. I want to get "somepageordirectory" if "page_id" is, for example, 1. else, redirect me to page.php. (excuse my english)

Comment: And for clarification - `page.php` is located at `/subdirectory/page.php`?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone yes. by now the issue pretty much solved, but how can I fix the trailing slash problem? (not display properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these rules :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory/  
#if an existent file or dir is requested,serve it immideatly 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#####
    # If user tries to access "page" without "get" then
RewriteRule ^page/ page.php [L]

# If user tries to access "page/1" or "pagename" then
RewriteRule ^page/1 page.php?page_id=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/pagename page.php?page_id=1 [L]

# If user tries to access "pagename" only then
RewriteRule ^pagename page.php?page_id=1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried now to add the `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` and refresh, but still nothing... any other ideas? thank you

Comment: Not only the Rule, but you also need to use both RewriteConds to prevent the rewrite loop.

Comment: I already had the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` above it

Comment: No, but now it makes 404 error when I try to access /subdirectory/pagename and redirect it to the parent folder (localhost/pagename instead of localhost/subdirectory/pagename)

Comment: Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: inside the "subdirectory" folder

Comment: Ok Remove the **RewriteBase** line

Comment: There's an error in the answer: The rules are **and** combined by default (is file **and** is directory) and need to be explicitly set to **or** `[OR]`

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone & starkeen **EDIT:** Works! thank you guys. but, how can I fix the trailing slash issue?

Comment: The answer could be further improved by an explanation, that a RewriteCond only affects the next RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

Since the main issue is already answered, here the additional issue with trailing slashes. Try to prepend a redirection rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will reply with a 301-redirection `[R=301]` and stop processing further rules. `[L]`= last rule

e.g. `/subdirectory/1/` is redirected to `/subdirectory/1`

Now it is up to the browser to request the redirected URL. Then the other rules will get in action.

Comment: Is it working in case of multiple get? I mean if I have for example `page.php?page_id=1&something=2&something_again=3` it will work and show page properly as `pagename/something/something` etc.? (sorry if I wrote it wrong or incorrect)

Comment: It would give a request like `/subdirectory/1/` back to the browser telling that the page can be found at `/subdirectory/1`. Then a new redirected request will be done by client and the other rules get in action.